# The Package Could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

- I have facing problem with this "Package could not be installed" error in wordpress when i am updating custom theme updates

Answer (score 0):

WordPress.org which hosts the plugins was having issues. Please try again, you will not face this issue anymore.

Comment: I have tried these many times but its not look like hosts plugin issue.

Comment: I see. Yesterday I faced same issue installing plugin from wp.org, which is resolved by now by the way. So yours could be different issue.